# My Julia script crashes in VS Code when I do some computations. How can I learn about the issue?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, julia, crash-reports

I wrote a MCMC script in Julia, which basically means that I ask the computer to compute up to *n* iterations of some function. This script executes perfectly when *n* is something relatively small like 1000 or 10000. However, when I bump the same script up to *n*=100000, my VS Code terminal just closes without reporting an error. This has been incredibly frustrating, as I would like to at least know what is causing the issue. While the terminal closes, the bottom bar shows that Julia is still "evaluating," but when I open "top" in my computer's terminal, it shows that Julia is not doing anything.

I honestly tried to create a minimal working example, but was unable to after a couple of hours. I have no idea how to even debug this problem, so any help is incredibly appreciated.

This is all happening on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, if it helps.

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you able to give us a minimal example? Then how are you expecting us to help? If you couldn't create a minimal example to behave the same as your real problem, then it's a specific problem of your code! So we've to see you're code to find a workaround.

Comment: @Shayan Somehow, I received two great answers that were helpful and informative. AND they helped me solve my issue. They must be magical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS code sometimes crashes when a file is too large. The larger the number, the larger the file size, so maybe your computer just isn't good enough to run your program.

I would suggest installing [Filesize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkxml.vscode-filesize) from the vscode extensions library, so you can test to see if the file size is any larger when inputting the larger number.

It could also be in the code, but I don't use Julia so I can't help you with that.

Comment: If this is the issue, is it possible that it would persistent if I run my code outside of VS Code? Or would this be strictly a VS-Code issue?

Comment: I would think that this is not strictly a vs-code issue, and is just a limitation of your computer. However it may work if you found a faster editor than VS-code. I would suggest exploring other editors like Atom or Sublime text, which may give better results.

Comment: You were correct. My file size was too large! I improved the efficiency of my code, and it's now running perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A good method to debug this is to use an external Julia REPL as described [here](https://www.julia-vscode.org/docs/stable/faq/#The-integrated-REPL-closes-when-the-Julia-process-crashes.-How-do-I-get-more-information-on-what%27s-going-on?).

In short,

1. Start a terminal (inside or outside of VS Code)
2. Start Julia in that terminal
3. Use the `Julia: Connect external REPL` command in VS Code
4. Copy the code snippet into the newly started REPL
5. Run the code that crashes Julia -- you'll still have access to everything that got printed before.

Another option is to enable the `julia.persistentSession.enabled` setting and restart your Julia process. You'll see that Julia now runs inside of tmux, which will also stay around after Julia exits.

Comment: I followed these steps and my terminal just said "killed." Where should I be able to have Julia be more verbose on the crash? Thank you.

Comment: Hm, weird. Try the `Terminal: Create New Terminal` command in VS Code and then start Julia manually there.